# Getting lookup field value without specifying the name for onChange field event

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a form, that could have `Contact` lookup field, or `User` lookup field, depending on the type of the person User wants to add. Only one of the fields is visible.

There is also `Name` text field, which I want to populate using name from lookup.

I want to add `onChange` function on lookup field to get the name and insert it in the `Name` field.

I know i can get field value like this:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ad_user").getValue();
```

But this way I would need to make separate functions for each field.
Is there a way for field with `onChange` event to get its own value without quoting that fields name? Something like this:

```
this.getValue();
```

That way I could use the same function for both fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When registering the onChange event handler pass [ExecutionContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328130.aspx) as the first parameter. You can then get the input value like so:

Event handler registration:

[image]

Handler:

```
function foo_onChange(executionContext) {
   var inputValue = executionContext.getEventSource().getValue();
}
```